# Get a string and replace a div with a new one

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery, I have got the html of a particular div on the page and using it as a string. However please can you tell me how I can remove each class in the string called "video-js" and replace it with another div? I am trying to get a few values off each "video-js" div before replacing it with the new div with those values.

This is what I have so far, but it's not writing back to the string.

```
var getTheCurrentResults = $(".titanLoaderControlList").html();

    var obj=$(getTheCurrentResults);
    $('.video-js',obj).each(function(){

        var theID = $(this).attr("id");
        var videoSRC = $(this).find(".vjs-tech").attr("src");
        var posterSRC = $(this).find(".vjs-tech").attr("poster");

        $(this).text("<div class='playButtonContainer'><div class='playButton'><div class='playButtonSymbol'></div></div></div><div class='videoInfo' data-video-id='"+theID+"' data-source-video='"+videoSRC+"'><img class='posterInfo' src='"+posterSRC+"'></div>");
    });
```

Comment: Could you please add your html to the question as well. It will make it easier to test our answer.

Comment: your explanation is not clear. Take your time and explain it clearly.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using `.html()` to replace the HTML content, not `.text()`.

```
var getTheCurrentResults = $(".titanLoaderControlList").html();

var obj=$(getTheCurrentResults);
$('.video-js',obj).each(function(){

    var theID = $(this).attr("id");
    var videoSRC = $(this).find(".vjs-tech").attr("src");
    var posterSRC = $(this).find(".vjs-tech").attr("poster");

    $(this).html("<div class='playButtonContainer'><div class='playButton'><div class='playButtonSymbol'></div></div></div><div class='videoInfo' data-video-id='"+theID+"' data-source-video='"+videoSRC+"'><img class='posterInfo' src='"+posterSRC+"'></div>");
});
```